# Storing data from a for loop in excel python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop, openpyxl

Want to store all the data from the for loop in an excel file, currently only storing the last output:

```
import pandas
import openpyxl

outputFile = 'outputData.xlsx'
    
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.getcwd() + '/sourceData.xlsx')
    
sheet = workbook["Sheet1"]
    
for i in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
       <I do some ops to copy the data>
       data = pyperclip.paste() #Want this data to be stored in the outPut excel, there is different input for every cell, so there will also be different output
       df = pd.DataFrame({'Address':[mapData]})
       df2 = pd.DataFrame()
       df2 = df2.append(df, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
    
writer = ExcelWriter(outputFile)
df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just move `df2` first initialization out of loop:

```py
...
# define df2 here, just once
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
       ... # your operations
       df = pd.DataFrame({'Address':[mapData]})
       # append df2 immediately after generation of df
       df2 = df2.append(df, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

# save as before
writer = ExcelWriter(outputFile)
df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```